# How to import European formated time series (thousands separator) into python or r

Tags: python, r, time-series, read-data

I run into some problems when importing stock data from a csv-file which has a European format, that looks like this:

```
Date ;Stock1;Stock2
03.05.2019 ;1.581,70;20,76
30.04.2019 ;1.588,46;20,72
```

currently I am using pandas' read_csv command. Which works fine for the second stock, and with a quick workaround, it's no problem to get the right time-index.

However, the thousands separator from stock1 gives me a headache. When it gets imported, python treats it as string and not as a float due to the "." . Trying out the "thousands" separator argument, it destroys my time stamp.

The version of the script so far that does not destroy the time stamp:

```
# Importing the data with a "," as decimal separator 
stock_data = pd.read_csv("stock_data.csv", sep = ";", decimal = ",")

# Time indexing
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.set_index(df["Date"], inplace = True)
```

Since I am really stuck, I would need some help with either finding a way to directly import such date, keeping the index intact while importing the rest as floats. Or, how to clean the csv-files before I import them.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Please have a look at the help files. In R, look at `?read.table`. There is a funcion argument dec. In python, you might use `pandas` to read in the csv. In that case look at the help doc for `read_csv`. There is a similar if not identical argument to this function. I usually go online to read the pandas documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using the read_csv from pandas, and I red the documentation for it, that's why I tried the "thousands" argument as described above. However, since the "date-separator" and the thousands-separator are identical, pandas has troubles to import both, the date and the number, correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(readr)
stock_data <- read_csv("stock_data.csv", 
    locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
View(house_pricing_test)
```